# Writing to QB File using python results in invalid format when opening in Qubicle

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

I can't for the life of me figure out how to make this [Qb Reader/Writer](https://github.com/dee-gmiterko/qb-reader/blob/master/qb-reader.py) library work. I have very simple script which puts a color in each voxel position. Colors for each voxel in Qubicle are supposed to be RGBA like `[255, 0, 0, 255]` for red with opacity of 100%. but it doesn't work. If I change `color` to be equal to an integer then it writes but that results in an invalid .qb file when opening in Qubicle. And also doesn't make any sense to save an integer as color. Can anyone enlighten me?

```
color = [255, 0, 0, 255]
data = [[[color for _ in range(6)] for _ in range(6)] for _ in range(6)]

for x in range(-3, 3):
    for y in range(-3, 3):
        for z in range(-3, 3):
            data[x + 3][y + 3][z + 3] = color

data_array = np.array(data)

with open('C:/out.qb', 'wb') as file:
    qb = Qb()
    layer = QbMatrix("main", data_array, (0, 0, 0))
    qb.matrixList.append(layer)
    qb.save(file)
```

The line that fails in the library is `file.write(struct.pack("I", matrix.data[x, y, z]))` if not using an integer with error `TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index`. Am I writing the `data` variable incorrectly?

I tried using a color `[255, 0, 0, 255]` which fails with error `TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index` and then tried using an integer which runs without errors but the resulting qb file is invalid and doesn't open with Qubicle